# Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".?

Tags: node.js, express, http, security, https

I'm trying to use an inline script in my project, and I keep getting this error:
'Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-hyQXPyDjuL7UGCz8hPIbJ2ZzKwE8uqNzvUJB9/9T6jc='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.'

I've viewed a bunch of other similar questions on here and they all say it has to do with a meta tag and to include something like this:
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />`

but that doesn't make a difference, I've removed all the meta tags from my `<head>`  and I still get the same error. where could this issue possibly be coming from other than the
`<head>` ? ive created my project with the express-generator but i cant find anything CSP in any of my files.

I'm completely lost on what's blocking the inline scripts, if I can provide any code please let me know but seeing as I have no idea what's causing it, i dont know what code to provide

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The CSP directive is not set in meta tag but in HTTP header.

Sice you marked the question with `node.js` and `express` tags, here's an example setting the CSP header in express:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 8080;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res
        .set("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src *; style-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'")
        .send("<html><head></head><body></body></html>");
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port %s", port);
});
```

Then you can see the CSP in the response headers:

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080
* Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:8080/
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.53.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Content-Security-Policy: default-src *; style-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 39
< ETag: W/"27-ghawzGh2y9RPAcFY59/zgzzszUE"
< Date: Tue, 17 Nov 2020 00:01:04 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=5
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Comment: Wait a minute... when did Content-Security-Policy become HTTP only? https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp#the_meta_tag

Comment: @Take-Some-Bytes Good catch. I didn't know about the `<meta>` tag option.

Comment: That's all fine and well. Maybe someone can tell the Facebook team so they can update GraphQL accordingly? I shouldn't have this error after setting up the most basic "hello world" example. How do I work around this using graphiql= true in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was the cheerio version. From 1.0.0-rc.12 to 1.0.0-rc.5 and worked fine after.